# Save matrices to .txt from a list

Tags: r, matrix

I have 32 matrices with different names need to be saved to `.txt`. I tried to add each matrix to a list and wanted to use loop to save from the list. I was trying with just one matrix called `mat_dis_func_742` first.

```
lsMatrix<-list()
name <- paste("mat_dis_func_", 742, sep="")
mat_dis_temp <- get(name)
lsMatrix[[name]] <- mat_dis_temp
write.table(lsMatrix[1],file=paste("Results/Test.txt"), row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, sep=";",quote=FALSE)
```

What is saved at the end is:

```
mat_dis_func_742.Class;mat_dis_func_742.Lower.bound;mat_dis_func_742.Upper.bound;mat_dis_func_742.n.x.;mat_dis_func_742.h.x.;mat_dis_func_742.f.x.
1;0.0908181818181818;0.339572192513369;2;0.666666666666667;0.666666666666667
2;0.339572192513369;0.588235294117647;1;0.333333333333333;1
```

And what i want is:

```
Class;Lower bound;Upper bound;n(x);h(x);f(x)
1;0.0908181818181818;0.339572192513369;2;0.666666666666667;0.666666666666667
2;0.339572192513369;0.588235294117647;1;0.333333333333333;1
```

So the column name is mixed with `mat_dis_func_742.`. I don't know how to fix it but i am not sure if this is the correct way to save many matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `write.table(lsMatrix[[1]],...)` instead of `write.table(lsMatrix[1],...)`. Here is an example:

```
# Problem
mat_742 <- diag(5)
colnames(mat_742) <- paste("column", 1:5, sep = "")
colnames(mat_742)
lsMatrix<-list()
name <- paste("mat_", 742, sep="")
mat_dis_temp <- get(name)
lsMatrix[[name]] <- mat_dis_temp
write.table(lsMatrix[1],file=paste("Test.txt"),
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, sep=";",quote=FALSE) #check file

# Solution
write.table(lsMatrix[[1]],file=paste("Test.txt"),
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, sep=";",quote=FALSE) #check file
```